# How to change part of a data.frame using a dynamic variable name for the df?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe "Tester" like below

```
Tester <- data.frame(A=c(1,3,5,7), B=c(2,4,6,8), C=0)
#A  B  C
#1  2  0
#3  4  0
#5  6  0
#7  8  0
```

I'd like to change the first two elements in column C so it reads c(1,1,0,0) by using a dynamically-determined variable name (stored in a string).

Because I'm looping this over several similar variable names, I'm operating with strings as variable names, and I've been able to do everything but this using get() and assign().

Because the variable name is stored in a string,

```
Tester[1:2,3] <- 1
```

is not possible.

When I try to use `get` or `assign`, R throws up "incorrect number of dimensions" errors

```
assign(Tester[1:2,3], 1)
or
assign(get("Tester")[1:2,3], 1)
```

and when I try double square brackets it throws up "incorrect number of subscripts."

I'm at a loss here...any help?

Comment: `Tester[1:2,3] <- 1` works fine on my machine. What does `str(Tester)` return?

Comment: Tester[1:2,3] <- 1 does work in theory. The issue is that I'm not using the variable name Tester, but the string "Tester" to access the dataframe. So to view Tester, I'd do View(get("Tester")) rather than View(Tester)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hacky workaround

```
Tester <- data.frame(A=c(1,3,5,7), B=c(2,4,6,8), C=0)

dfname <- "Tester"
colname <- "C"

df <- get(dfname)
df[1:2, colname] <- 1
assign(dfname, df)

get(dfname)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```
> dfName <- "mydf"
> mydf <- data.frame(A = c(1,3,5,7), B = c(2,4,6,8), C = c(0,0,0,0))
> mydf
  A B C
1 1 2 0
2 3 4 0
3 5 6 0
4 7 8 0
> 
> mydf <- get(dfName)
> mydf$C[1:2] <-1
> get(dfName)
  A B C
1 1 2 1
2 3 4 1
3 5 6 0
4 7 8 0
```

Notice that once you find the df, you just save it into your variable of choice and then print.

Comment: This wouldn't work, because I'm not using the variable mydf, but am accessing it via the string "mydf." So, for example, to view mydf, I'd do View(get("mydf"))